# SPA: Separating backend administration from client side

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal, durandal-2.0

I’m working on a SPA built with DurandalJS, which is hosted on `app.example.com`. The API is hosted on `api.example.com`. We're now planning to add backend administration for ourselves, to overlook our clients. We'll each have an account and we'll be able to manage our client stuff.

What we're trying to figure out is where to host the backend.

1. If we keep it on the `app` subdomain, we'll only have to add a new role (admin) to the existing application, but this will allow regular users to log in ti the backend if our credentials are somehow leaked.
2. If we clone the existing application to `admin.example.com`, we'll always have to worry about the code being in sync, but it will be safer, because the `admin` subdomain will be closed to the public and the login for admins will require a different set of api and private keys.

How should we handle this? If we go with #2, are there better ways to share code between two apps without the extra headaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my current app structure:

- /_css/
- /_img/
- /_js/

  - /app/
  - /lib/
- index.html

After reading both answers, I ended up separating the apps while keeping them under the same roof.

- /_css/
- /_img/
- /_js/

  - /app/
  - **/backend/**
  - /lib/
- **index-app.html**
- **index-backend.html**

This allows an easier way to manage and switch between the apps. I don't have to worry about keeping the css, the images and the libraries in sync or creating a new git repo for the backend.

I've also updated my `Gruntfile.js` to include a separate building process for the app and the backend. So locally the apps will be under the same `/_js` folder, but on the server, they'll be on separate domains.

I should have been more specific with my question and include the fact that my problem was more with how I can manage both apps locally, rather than on the server.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

I personally like the second approach to go with different subdomains.
Duplicating the codebase is not really necessary since you can leverage the cool features RequireJS provides to map aliases to your modules. The importance here is that through extracting the business logic into modules you can serve different implementations.

I've created a small GitHub Repo called [durandal-multisite](https://github.com/zewa666/durandal-multisite) to explain in detail how you would proceed.

The general idea is to:

1. Keep the same viewmodels/views
2. Extract businesslogic (should be anyway done to follow proper SoC)
3. Create 2 main.js implementations (frontend/backend)
4. The respective main.js setup a RequireJS map to the aliases requested by your viewmodels
   which then deliver the concrete module implementation

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to distinguish between creating subdomains that point to the same application or creating two separate applications.

I think in order to give a full answer, we need to identify some important aspects of your app first:

- How is your authentication and authentication implemented? Is it part of the SPA? Is it before loading the SPA?
- Will the code of the application be 100% the same as the admin application? What do you mean by keep in sync?

Making some assumptions I could give you some answer, it might not be accurate but could help you:

Subdomains are cool, you get some information upfront (which subdomain the user is trying to access) so you can qualify requests easily and determine some stuff before actually hitting the application server. However, I don't think your problem here is in which subdomain the application should live.

The first thing you need to answer is how you would qualify a user from being an Admin and a regular User. Obviously you should not rely on a subdomain to do so. Probably this logic would live in the login process based on some data (probably from a DB).

The next thing that you need to know is how your application changes depending on the role:

- If your application will be 100% the same (same code)  and will react dynamically based on the role that is logged, you don't really need anything special. All you need is make sure that  your application is secure enough to not allow regular users to do admin stuff.

  - You could use the subdomain and some extra logic so only Admins can use the subdomain. However this is only some "sugar" security to make some separation. The app needs still needs to manage roles and permissions consistently.

  -
- If your application is not using the same codebase, you need to determine during the logging process in the web application which role is logging in and which SPA application it should send to the browser. To do so, you need a separate logging page or have a modular SPA that can load modules at dynamically.

  - Probably you would like to reuse some code between applications (admin & user facing apps). You will have some challenges reusing parts of the codebase.
  - You don't need to worry that much about permissions and roles in the user app but you need a secure logging process.

(Just a reminder) In any event, SPA's should contain logic to manage roles and permissions for the sake of consistency and to avoid user confusion. The main security management is in your API. The goal in any SPA that has authentication and authorization is to have a secure API behind.